# What is Ubuntu Advantage?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

What is Ubuntu Advantage and how can it help my business?

Comment: Why is `ubuntu-advantage-tools` installed by default on Diigtal Ocean Ubuntu distros?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ubuntu Advantage is paid support for Ubuntu Server and Desktop. It will provide support, legal assurance, a knowledge base, and Landscape. Landscape is management and monitoring tool to assist you with managing your servers and desktops. By legal assurance they will take care of intellectual property infringement legal claims brought against customers in their use of Ubuntu

Answer (score 15):

Ubuntu Advantage is a layered enterprise support service provided by Canonical to businesses.

These services can help your business successfully deploy and run a Ubuntu environment with expert assistance at hand when you require it.

Desktop and Server packages are broken down into a number of features, all covering:

1. Technical Support
2. Access to the Canonical Knowledge base
3. Landscape (Online systems management tool providing update management, scripting and monitoring across all your Ubuntu systems)
4. Legal Assurance (Canonical will cover intellectual property infringement and any legal claims brought against customers in their use of Ubuntu)

Further to the above there are a number of layered additional options for different support coverage on both Desktop and Server.

Ubuntu Advantage Desktop is broken down into two packages, Standard & Advanced.

Ubuntu Advantage Server is broken down into three packages, Essential, Standard & Advanced.

You can find the full description of these packages and the program in general on [this page](https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage-service-description) on the Ubuntu website.